# Change encoding from Default to Unicode for encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, encoding, .net-4.5

I have a project where everything that is stored in database is encrypted. For encoding we use `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text)`.

The problem is that now the client wants to add support for polish (and other nordic) characters and using the `Default` encoding doesn't work, the polish characters get converted to english characters (e.g Ą gets converted to A).

I can't change the encoding (`Unicode` seems to work) as the previous data will be lost.

Is there any way to get around this and add support for new characters while keeping the old data?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear; you realise that "encoding" is not "encrypting", but I suppose you encrypt the byte array you get from encoding your string data?

Then I'd suggest either decrypting and re-encoding and re-encrypting all existing data using UTF-8 (the most efficient encoding for Western alphabets), *or* add a "version" or "encoding" column indicating with which encoding the data was encrypted.